# SpringSecurity, how to log failed attempts due to enabled==false, grails 2.5

Tags: grails, logging, spring-security

Our authentication domain object, Operator, as boolean enabled on it.
When we set this to false, SpringSecurity + grails magically fails login attempts with the message "Sorry, your account is disabled".

We want to log such attempts.  Presumably, there is some kind of listener or handler, which DOES NOT require us to implement the logic (I.e. grails just informs us that the user was rejected, not that we now have to decide if the user should be rejected or not).

We already log failed password checks, and if they fail because they had too many login attempts - we don't want it to catch those events, just the rejection due to `enabled == false`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve it easily. First modify your `Config.groovy` so that it can redirect to a particular action on login failure:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = "/login/authfail"
// For AJAX based authentication
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.ajaxAuthFailUrl = "/login/authfail"
```

Now define a `LoginController` with action `authfail` as following:

```
def authfail() {
    String msg = ""
    Exception exception = session[WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION]

    // print the kind of message you want either due to account locked, enabled = false, password expired = true and others
    log.debug "User login failed due to [${exception?.message}]"
    if (exception) {
        if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.expired")
        } else if (exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.passwordExpired")
        } else if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.disabled")
        } else if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.locked")
        } else {
            msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.fail")
        }
    }

    // redirect or respond acccordingly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution Solution after [RTFM](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/)

MySecurityEventListener.groovy:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event. AuthenticationFailureDisabledEvent

class MySecurityEventListener
        implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureDisabledEvent> {

    void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureDisabledEvent event) {
        println "DISABLED LOGGON!!!!"
    }
}
```

Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
```

spring/resource.groovy

```
import com.nektan.me.bla.MySecurityEventListener
beans = {
        mySecurityEventListener(MySecurityEventListener)
}
```

This prints the message.
However, it is not possible to access the grails services from inside the event listener, the injection does not work.  We have a grails service which logs security events to the DB, which we haven't found a way to use from inside this callback.